# Solution for this datatable reorganization?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

| Date | Segment | Variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2021 | XXX | aa_a_1 | 10 |
| 31-12-2021 | XXX | bbb_1 | 11 |
| 31-12-2021 | XXX | ccc_1 | 12 |
| 31-01-2022 | XXX | aa_a_2 | 13 |
| 31-01-2022 | XXX | bbb_2 | 14 |
| 31-01-2022 | XXX | ccc_2 | 15 |
| 28-02-2022 | XXX | aa_a_3 | 16 |
| 28-02-2022 | XXX | bbb_3 | 17 |
| 28-02-2022 | XXX | ccc_3 | 18 |
| 31-03-2022 | XXX | aa_a_4 | 19 |
| 31-03-2022 | XXX | bbb_4 | 20 |
| 31-03-2022 | XXX | ccc_4 | 21 |
| 30-04-2022 | XXX | aa_a_5 | 22 |
| 30-04-2022 | XXX | bbb_5 | 23 |
| 30-04-2022 | XXX | ccc_5 | 24 |
| 31-05-2022 | XXX | aa_a_6 | 25 |
| 31-05-2022 | XXX | bbb_6 | 26 |
| 31-05-2022 | XXX | ccc_6 | 27 |
| 30-06-2022 | XXX | aa_a_7 | 28 |
| 30-06-2022 | XXX | bbb_7 | 29 |
| 30-06-2022 | XXX | ccc_7 | 30 |
| 31-07-2022 | XXX | aa_a_8 | 31 |
| 31-07-2022 | XXX | bbb_8 | 32 |
| 31-07-2022 | XXX | ccc_8 | 33 |
| 31-08-2022 | XXX | aa_a_9 | 34 |
| 31-08-2022 | XXX | bbb_9 | 35 |
| 31-08-2022 | XXX | ccc_9 | 36 |
| 30-09-2022 | XXX | aa_a_10 | 37 |
| 30-09-2022 | XXX | bbb_10 | 38 |
| 30-09-2022 | XXX | ccc_10 | 39 |
| 31-10-2022 | XXX | aa_a_11 | 40 |
| 31-10-2022 | XXX | bbb_11 | 41 |
| 31-10-2022 | XXX | ccc_11 | 42 |
| 30-11-2022 | XXX | aa_a_12 | 43 |
| 30-11-2022 | XXX | bbb_12 | 44 |
| 30-11-2022 | XXX | ccc_12 | 45 |
| 31-12-2021 | YYY | aa_a_1 | 46 |
| 31-12-2021 | YYY | bbb_1 | 47 |
| 31-12-2021 | YYY | ccc_1 | 48 |
| 31-01-2022 | YYY | aa_a_2 | 49 |
| 31-01-2022 | YYY | bbb_2 | 50 |
| 31-01-2022 | YYY | ccc_2 | 51 |
| 28-02-2022 | YYY | aa_a_3 | 52 |
| 28-02-2022 | YYY | bbb_3 | 53 |
| 28-02-2022 | YYY | ccc_3 | 54 |
| 31-03-2022 | YYY | aa_a_4 | 55 |
| 31-03-2022 | YYY | bbb_4 | 56 |
| 31-03-2022 | YYY | ccc_4 | 57 |
| 30-04-2022 | YYY | aa_a_5 | 58 |
| 30-04-2022 | YYY | bbb_5 | 59 |
| 30-04-2022 | YYY | ccc_5 | 60 |
| 31-05-2022 | YYY | aa_a_6 | 61 |
| 31-05-2022 | YYY | bbb_6 | 62 |
| 31-05-2022 | YYY | ccc_6 | 63 |
| 30-06-2022 | YYY | aa_a_7 | 64 |
| 30-06-2022 | YYY | bbb_7 | 65 |
| 30-06-2022 | YYY | ccc_7 | 66 |
| 31-07-2022 | YYY | aa_a_8 | 67 |
| 31-07-2022 | YYY | bbb_8 | 68 |
| 31-07-2022 | YYY | ccc_8 | 69 |
| 31-08-2022 | YYY | aa_a_9 | 70 |
| 31-08-2022 | YYY | bbb_9 | 71 |
| 31-08-2022 | YYY | ccc_9 | 72 |
| 30-09-2022 | YYY | aa_a_10 | 73 |
| 30-09-2022 | YYY | bbb_10 | 74 |
| 30-09-2022 | YYY | ccc_10 | 75 |
| 31-10-2022 | YYY | aa_a_11 | 76 |
| 31-10-2022 | YYY | bbb_11 | 77 |
| 31-10-2022 | YYY | ccc_11 | 78 |
| 30-11-2022 | YYY | aa_a_12 | 79 |
| 30-11-2022 | YYY | bbb_12 | 80 |
| 30-11-2022 | YYY | ccc_12 | 81 |

And so on to a total of 24 different dates and 'aaa','bbb' and 'ccc' from 1 to 24.

And the desired output would be:

| Date | Segment | aa_a | bbb | ccc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-12-2021 | XXX | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 31-01-2022 | XXX | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 31-12-2021 | YYY | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 31-01-2022 | YYY | 19 | 20 | 21 |

And so on...

Any idea? I'm blocked at this point.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just reshaping. Since you mentioned [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```r
library(data.table)
dcast(Date +  Segment ~ Variable, value.var = "value",
      data = DT[, Variable := gsub("_[0-9]+$", "", Variable)])
#           Date Segment aa_a bbb ccc
#  1: 28-02-2022     XXX   16  17  18
#  2: 28-02-2022     YYY   52  53  54
#  3: 30-04-2022     XXX   22  23  24
#  4: 30-04-2022     YYY   58  59  60
#  5: 30-06-2022     XXX   28  29  30
#  6: 30-06-2022     YYY   64  65  66
#  7: 30-09-2022     XXX   37  38  39
#  8: 30-09-2022     YYY   73  74  75
#  9: 30-11-2022     XXX   43  44  45
# 10: 30-11-2022     YYY   79  80  81
# 11: 31-01-2022     XXX   13  14  15
# 12: 31-01-2022     YYY   49  50  51
# 13: 31-03-2022     XXX   19  20  21
# 14: 31-03-2022     YYY   55  56  57
# 15: 31-05-2022     XXX   25  26  27
# 16: 31-05-2022     YYY   61  62  63
# 17: 31-07-2022     XXX   31  32  33
# 18: 31-07-2022     YYY   67  68  69
# 19: 31-08-2022     XXX   34  35  36
# 20: 31-08-2022     YYY   70  71  72
# 21: 31-10-2022     XXX   40  41  42
# 22: 31-10-2022     YYY   76  77  78
# 23: 31-12-2021     XXX   10  11  12
# 24: 31-12-2021     YYY   46  47  48
#           Date Segment aa_a bbb ccc
```

FYI, regex (and an [extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272) about regex):

- `_` is a literal underscore character.
- `[0-9]` means a (single) *"character class"* that contains characters between "0" and "9", not *numbers* between 0 and 9. For instance, `19` is two characters, each are between 0 and 9.
- `+` means *"one or more"*.
- `$` means *"end of string"*.

So `"aaa_24"` and `"aa_a_9999999"` will be updated; `"aaa_"` and `"aaa_z"` and `"aaa_24b"` will not.

---

Data

```r
DT <- setDT(structure(list(Date = c("31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "30-04-2022", "30-04-2022", "30-04-2022", "31-05-2022", "31-05-2022", "31-05-2022", "30-06-2022", "30-06-2022", "30-06-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-08-2022", "31-08-2022", "31-08-2022", "30-09-2022", "30-09-2022", "30-09-2022", "31-10-2022", "31-10-2022", "31-10-2022", "30-11-2022", "30-11-2022",  "30-11-2022", "31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "28-02-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "31-03-2022", "30-04-2022", "30-04-2022", "30-04-2022", "31-05-2022", "31-05-2022", "31-05-2022", "30-06-2022", "30-06-2022", "30-06-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-07-2022", "31-08-2022", "31-08-2022", "31-08-2022", "30-09-2022", "30-09-2022", "30-09-2022", "31-10-2022", "31-10-2022", "31-10-2022", "30-11-2022", "30-11-2022",  "30-11-2022"), Segment = c("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY",  "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY"), Variable = c("aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc",  "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc", "aa_a", "bbb", "ccc"), value = 10:81), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: This could work.

Problem is that Variable is going from 1 to 24, and is giving to me some strange output...

Comment: If you update your data to better represent the issue, I can look into it.

Comment: I updated the table but I put 12 instead of 24; also I tried `dcast(Date +  Segment ~ Variable, value.var = "value",data = DT[, Variable := gsub("_[1-24]+$", "", Variable])`

Comment: Also, I have edited the Variable `aaa_X` to `aa_a_X` so maybe `gsub` will not work...

Comment: There was a typo in the answer causing a syntax/parsing problem, it must have been messed up when I pasted to SO, sorry about that. I've fixed that and updated to your new data. The new column name did not change `gsub`'s behavior, I added a quick explanation on the regex.

Comment: Thank you very much, that'll work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We can `separate` the 'Variable' column into 'two' and then use `pivot_wider` to reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  separate(Variable, into = c('Var1', 'Var2')) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var1, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-Var2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Date       Segment   aaa   bbb   ccc
  <chr>      <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 31-12-2021 XXX        10    11    12
2 31-01-2022 XXX        13    14    15
3 31-12-2021 YYY        16    17    18
4 31-01-2022 YYY        19    20    21
```

---

Or use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Date + Segment ~ trimws(Variable, whitespace = "_.*"))
         Date Segment aaa bbb ccc
1: 31-01-2022     XXX  13  14  15
2: 31-01-2022     YYY  19  20  21
3: 31-12-2021     XXX  10  11  12
4: 31-12-2021     YYY  16  17  18
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", 
"31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-12-2021", "31-12-2021", 
"31-12-2021", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022", "31-01-2022"), Segment = c("XXX", 
"XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", "YYY", 
"YYY", "YYY"), Variable = c("aaa_1", "bbb_1", "ccc_1", "aaa_2", 
"bbb_2", "ccc_2", "aaa_1", "bbb_1", "ccc_1", "aaa_2", "bbb_2", 
"ccc_2"), value = 10:21), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: I just edited the post, so it is a total of 24 different dates and variables. Also, I am not able to add 'whitespace' in my trimws function.

Comment: @gojkokacar it shouldn't matter as the solution i posted is general.  `trimws` have that argument.  Not clear.  Please check your R version, package versions

Comment: I have this one: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.97/topics/trimws when I put trimws function in help page. Sadly I am not able to update R version...

Comment: @gojkokacar `trimws` is a `base R` function.  You don't need any packages

Comment: @gojkokacar you can check [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/trimws)

Comment: I know @akrun, but it seems that 'whitespace' is not being recognized in this function in my case... a bit strange. Maybe with a higher R version could work..

Comment: you may have loaded the package memisc, thus the trimws from base R is masked from that function

Comment: @gojkokacar you could use `::` if there is a masking i.e. `base::trimws("hello_1", whitespace = "_.*")#
[1] "hello"`

Comment: Still the same issue with base::trimws, it seems my base function of trimws is not recognizing 'whitespace'

Comment: My #R version is 3.5.3

Comment: @gojkokacar your column names in the new update pattern is different.  Please post only the one that mimics your data.